# RestSharp fails on saving results

Tags: c#, restsharp

Response is successful, i can view it in Visual Studio, but when i try to get returned data, its null.

This is API https://yoda-api.appspot.com/api/v1/yodish?text=I%20am%20yoda

And this is my code:

```
public class YodishModel
    {
        public string yodish { get; set; }
    }

    public class YodishResult
    {
        public YodishModel Result { get; set; }
    }
public class YodishService : iService
    {
        public string GetText(string text)
        {
            Lazy<RestClient> client = new Lazy<RestClient>(() => new RestClient($"http://yoda-api.appspot.com/api/v1/yodish?text={text}"));

            var request = new RestRequest();

            var response = client.Value.Execute<YodishResult>(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return response.Data.Result.yodish;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public string ToUrl(string text)
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);
        }
    }
```

Response is successful, i can view the result, but `Result` is null (`NullPointerException`).

Also, is there a way to use parameters here instead of using string interpolation? 'text' is part of the URL which is officially not a paremeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you were deserializing using a mismatched object. This is what I did to fix it:

```
public class YodishModel
    {
        public string yodish { get; set; }
    }

    public class YodishService
    {
        public string GetText(string text)
        {
            Lazy<RestClient> client = new Lazy<RestClient>(() => new RestClient($"https://yoda-api.appspot.com/api/v1/"));

            var request = new RestRequest($"yodish").AddQueryParameter("text", Uri.EscapeDataString(text), true);
            var response = client.Value.Execute<YodishModel>(request);


            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return Uri.UnescapeDataString(response.Data.yodish);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I also added the AddQueryParameter, as you mentioned.

Comment: I don't get why this works and mine not, it seems to be identical but with one extra class. And two more questions - 1. Why `AddQueryParameter` and not `AddParameter`? 2. Why `$"yodish"` in `RestRequest`? 
I probably need more practice in RestSharp, but well, this is why i'm doing this.

Comment: Ok i think i got it. And i managed to do it with `AddParemeter`. Thanks for help, marking as solved.